# How do I access the DLC in Dragon Age: Origins?

Tags: dragon-age-origins

I recently bought the ultimate edition of *Dragon Age: Origins*, which includes the *Awakening* expansion pack and all the DLC. It looks like the DLC is modular and isn't integrated into the game; do I need to play them separately? How do I access them?

Comment: the DAO DLCs integrate afaik except for witch hunt.  But awakening is a different module (its a standalone expansion rather than a DLC).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following DLC are integrated into the main game, and you can access them any time after you gain access to the region map:

- Warden's Keep
- The Stone Prisoner
- Return to Ostagar

The following are more-or-less item packs, and you should have access to them by the time you gain access to your party's camp:

- Any promotional/pre-order bonuses
- Feastday gifts and pranks

The following are separate stories requiring you to select them as you start a new game:

- The Darkspawn Chronicles
- Leliana's Song
- The Golems of Amgarrak<sup>1</sup>
- Witch Hunt<sup>1</sup>
- Awakening<sup>1</sup>

<sup>Note 1</sup>: Can import your character from *Dragon Age: Origins*, but your companions don't follow you and you can't access the main storyline or the other DLC (except for the non-Feastday items that you might've imported with your character).

Answer (score 1):

They tie into the main game.  When you view your map, the DLC will unlock a few places that you can visit at **anytime.**

[image]

[source](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/File:Map_-_World.jpg)

The DLC should be shown as a place you can visit with a Golden tint: Such as the The Stone Prisoner, etc.

[More info listed here.](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/DLC)

To clarify, the DLC can be played side by side with the original Dragon Age: Origins.
The Awakening expansion pack must be played separately as those events take place after origins.

Comment: I've installed them all, do I need to actually activate them?  I'm only about 10 hours in.

Comment: nevermind.... i couldn't see the map you attached.  This is great. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, I had to get the source first.  If this helps, feel free to up vote and Check :)